# Jpos Generic Packager and Multi use Fields

Tags: jpos

I'm currently working on a jpos project and looking at the documentation for the message formats there are fields that have multiple usages. For example field 104 has 2 usages one is a fixed length Char value. The second usage for field 104 is a TLV field. Is there any way to set up the generic packager to allow for both the fields to work or do I need a separate XML for each usage?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest solution is to use field 104 as an opaque field (i.e. `org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLBINARY`) and then handle the payload from your higher level application.